# Is there some reason for updating to SQL Server 2016 Express for ordinary simple scenarios?

Tags: sql-server-2016-express

I have noticed that Microsoft recently released [SQL Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en/server-cloud/products/sql-server/default.aspx). There a lot of new features involving clouds, security, encryption, But I can hardly find something useful for me. I don't use cloud, I don't use failover, I don't use encryption. I mean I have only Express edition with ASP.NET MVC app which use simple SELECT, JOINS, INSERT INTO and fulltext queries.

Update is not simple for me because the SQL Server 2016 requires at least Windows Server 2012 R2, which means an update of server as well. Furthermore I cannot have Windows 7 on developer machine.

Does it worth the update or should I keep 2012 version? Is there any improvement in such simple SQL scenarios and query executions in SQL Server 2016 Express edition?

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you currently have? Also, what features are critical for you and will make you finally take the decision of upgrading or not?

Comment: I have version SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Then there may be a reason for you to upgrade as from SQL Server 2014 onwards there is a new cardinality estimator that may give your application a performance boost,